# Why am I getting a command error installing pyautogui with pip3 (macos)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyautogui

I tried installing the pyautogui:

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

I get this error code:
[picture of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCVUf.png)

It runs for every pyautogui version, trying to find one that satisfies the requirements.

I have pillow, pyobj-core and pyobj.
I am on macOS Monterey version 12.1

Solution:

run:
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3

if command doesn't work, you have to change the path of python3

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

then:
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

finally:
pip3 install pyautogui

Comment: I think my pip path is wrong: /usr/local/bin/pip3 . I trying updating the location using: export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python:${PATH}   but it doesn't change the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this

```
python3 -m pip install pyautogui
```

this is based on [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: "python3 -m pip install pyautogui" didn't work same error. edit: I learned how to reply

Comment: I think you need to install setup-tools first mate.
you can see here https://pypi.org/project/distribute/#installation-instructions

since the original setuptools doesn't support Python 3.
I hope it helps

Comment: I get a the same error when installing distribute